# Why the textbox value is not reflecting on click of buttons?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to design a basic calculator app using React which is having the below design.

[image]

There are two textboxes in the gray colored area, first one is for the input and the second one is for the output.

In my local, when I click the buttons for ex: 8 and 3 and try to do any of the mathematical operations, the value doesn't show up in the input textbox and also the final result is not visible in the output textbox.

I have tried the below solution:

As can be seen in the below code, there is a handleClick function which is handling the click of each of the buttons and this function is being passed as props to the Button component.

Inside the handleClick event using the switch keyword we are performing different operations on clicking different buttons.

Problem: Inside the '=' switch case, the below line of code

ans = eval(this.state.question);

is giving empty result.

Expected Output: The ans variable should produce the correct value based on the mathematical operation.

```
handleClick(event){

    // get the value from the target element (button)
    const value = event.target.value;
    
    switch (value) {
        case '=': {
    
        // if it's an equal sign, use the eval module
        // to evaluate the question ,convert the answer
        // (in number) to String
        if (this.state.question!=='')
         {
            var ans='';
                try
                {
                    ans = eval(this.state.question);
                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    this.setState({answer: "Math Error"});
                }
                if (ans === undefined)
                    this.setState({answer: "Math Error"});
    
                // update answer in our state.
                else
                    this.setState({ answer: ans , question: ''});
                break;
         }
         break;
        }
        case 'Clear': {
    
        // if it's the Clears sign, just clean our
        // question and answer in the state
        this.setState({ question: '', answer: '' });
        break;
        }
    
        case 'Delete': {
        var str = this.state.question;
        str = str.substr(0,str.length-1);
        this.setState({question: str});
        break;
        }
    
    default: {
    
        // for every other command, update the answer in the state
        this.setState({ question: this.state.question += value})
        break;
        }
    }
    }
```

```
render()
    {
    return (
    <div className="frame">
    <CalculatorTitle value="GeeksforGeeks Calculator"/>
    <div className="mainCalc">
    <OutputScreen/>
    <div className="button-row">
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'Clear'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'Delete'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'.'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'/'}/>
    </div>
    <div className="button-row">
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'7'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'8'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'9'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'*'}/>
    </div>
    <div className="button-row">
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'4'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'5'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'6'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'-'}/>
    </div>
    <div className="button-row">
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'1'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'2'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'3'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'+'}/>
    </div>
    <div className="button-row">
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'0'}/>
    <Button handleClick = {this.handleClick}
     label={'='}/>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your buttons are not having any value attribute. Rather try using label attribute `event.target.label` to access the value or you can also use `event.target.innerText` to access values of button. As per my understanding of your code this should work.

Comment: I have already one button component in which I am having the value attribute. Below is the code for the same. const Button = (props) => {
return (
 <input
 type="button"
 value={props.label} onClick = {props.handleClick}
 />
);
}

Comment: Issue is now solved.